# Which is better, constants or variables?

Tags: php, memory, optimization

We can assign values to constant or variables. Which one is better from a memory and optimization point of view?

```
define("X",5);
```

or

```
$x = 5;
```

Does in both case integer occupy same memory? Which one take more memory space and faster to run?

I have analyzed this task 100k times in php.exe on command prompt and explaining here...

```
//Defining a constant Test
$DefConst_TimeStart = microtime();
$DefConst_MemStart = memory_get_usage();
for($i=1;$i<=100000;$i++){
    define("x$i",$i);
}
$DefConst_MemEnd = memory_get_usage();
$DefConst_TimeEnd = microtime();
//Variable test
$Variable_TimeStart = microtime();
$Variable_MemStart = memory_get_usage();
for($i=1;$i<=100000;$i++){
    ${"x".$i} = $i;
}
$Variable_MemEnd = memory_get_usage();
$Variable_TimeEnd = microtime();

//Output of the results
echo "Define Constant: Time: ".($DefConst_TimeEnd - $DefConst_TimeStart)." ms | Memory: ".($DefConst_MemEnd - $DefConst_MemStart)." Bytes\n";
echo "Setting Variable: Time: ".($Variable_TimeEnd - $Variable_TimeStart)." ms | Memory: ".($Variable_MemEnd - $Variable_MemStart)." Bytes\n";
```

And according to analysis:

Time taken: Variable is faster in execution rather than constant

Memory usage: Constant occupy less memory than variable

Output image

[image]

You can download file from github to test it

[Benchmark example to test speed and memory usage](https://github.com/marmikbhatt/Benchmark_Geek)

let me know am i on right track or not?

Comment: i have gone through that question but i could not get exact answer regarding memory optimization

Comment: I tried benchmarking a simple constant vs. variable but there's a limit to online tools. [Constant Bench](http://3v4l.org/6KVGh/perf#tabs) vs. [Variable Bench](http://3v4l.org/V7VAY/perf#tabs)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between assigning a single variable and defining a single constant is likely to be so tiny that it would be dwarfed by random variation in the rest of the program.

Both are high-level constructs registering an association between a name and a value in a complex type structure, subject to all sorts of optimisations and special cases in the underlying engine.

If you had hundreds of such definitions, you might begin to notice a small difference, but at that point there's something wrong with the design of your program.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using the Variable simply because declaring the variable itself doesn't need to call a function while define is a function that will define a value.